# Add /usr/local to path for ./configure

Tags: linux, static-libraries, configure

I am trying to install `libvisio-0.1.5` which requires `librevenge-0-0`. I get the error:

```
checking for REVENGE... no
configure: error: Package requirements (
        librevenge-0.0
) were not met:
```

I just installed librevenge and I have all the pkg-config info, but they are in `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` and not in `/usr/lib/pkgconfig`.

How can I tell `./configure` to look always and by default at both `/usr/lib/pkgconfig` and `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`?

I tried

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
./configure
```

And I have:

```
$ pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config
/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig
```

Comment: What about REVENGE_CFLAGS & REVENGE_LIBS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
```

Comment: This is the configuration by default

Answer (score 2):

---

This command has always worked perfectly for me ....

```
export PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig/
```

---

---